# CKAN missing datastore tab / upload options

Tags: datastore, ckan

I've followed install instructions from source in here:
http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html

And from here:
http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html

I added the datastore entry in ckan.plugins setting.
I did **Test the setup** and it worked.

However, when editing/creating a resource in CKAN web interface, the datastore tab or upload to datastore option does not show up.

1. This a new install on a Ubuntu 16.04.
2. CKAN version 2.6.2

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
After installing datapusher, and trying to upload a resource in the DataStore tab, came up another error, which is specified in here: [CKAN error upload to datastore (with datapusher)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186954/ckan-error-upload-to-datastore-with-datapusher)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link. It has datapusher installation for both developement and production installation (paster and Apache). And how to start datapsuher for respective servers

Don't forget to add Datapusher plugin and Datapusher URL in development/production.ini

[Data Pusher Documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Not only datastore, you should also add datapusher in your .ini file, and you will be able to see Datastore tab from where you can upload resources on Datastore. Also in your .ini file you must set up ckan.storage_path location