# CKAN error upload to datastore (with datapusher)

Tags: ckan

After installing DataPusher (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029911/ckan-missing-datastore-tab-upload-options) question), tried to upload a file in the Datastore tab, come up this error:

[image]

Versions:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- CKAN version 2.6.2 (installed from source)
- DataPusher (development installation)

Thank you

Comment: Can you please tell us what is the file type you are trying to upload to the datastore? Datapusher works only with tabular data files. Please see a similar issue [here](https://github.com/ckan/datapusher/issues/91).

Comment: You can see from the Upload Log, it is KML.

Comment: I am sorry I did not realize that. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKAN Datapusher only supports structured data in CSV or Excel formats. You are trying to upload a file of type KML which is not supported.

Please take a look at the official documentation for more, [here](http://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/using.html#triggering-pushes) and [here](http://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/).

Please also check [this](https://github.com/ckan/datapusher/issues/91) Github issue, where you can see the reply from one of the developers to a question describing a similar problem to yours.